# Calling the event emitter before the event handler in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, events, event-handling, eventemitter

I am going through [this code](https://github.com/vithalreddy/nodeJS-socketIO-chat-app/blob/master/libs/chat.js) and I have seen the nodejs event emitter being called before the event handler was defined([this line](https://github.com/vithalreddy/nodeJS-socketIO-chat-app/blob/master/libs/chat.js#L44) and [this line](https://github.com/vithalreddy/nodeJS-socketIO-chat-app/blob/master/libs/chat.js#L181)).

When I try to replicate the same, no event gets handled.

```
    eventEmitter.emit('event');

    eventEmitter.on('event', () => {
        console.log('event handled');
    });
```

When you put the event emitter after the event handler 
'*event handled* ' gets logged.

Is [the code on GitHub](https://github.com/vithalreddy/nodeJS-socketIO-chat-app/blob/master/libs/chat.js) wrong? Or does it still work because it is in a module and there is a way the module is imported that allows it to work? Kindly explain. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The event emission on line 44 is inside of the handler being bound to the ioChat's "connection" event which is not invoked before the binding of eventEmitter's "get-all-users" event on line 181. So even though the line where the event is invoked comes first, it will not be invoked first.

Example:

```
eventEmitter.on('connection', () => {
  console.log('this should log second');
  eventEmitter.emit('someEvent');
});

eventEmitter.on('someEvent', () => {
  console.log('this should log third');
});

console.log('this should log first');
eventEmitter.emit('connection');
```

Comment: So you are saying that when you import the module exported on line 18 the handlers are first 'registered' before any connection can be evoked by the client?

Comment: Almost. The registration doesn't happen when you import the module, but rather when the exported function gets invoked.

Comment: I think I now understand. Correct me if I am wrong: Before the ioChat's "connection" event is called, Nodejs has already 'seen' the event handler on line 181?

Comment: Hey, could you please check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57440266/what-is-the-advantage-of-using-event-emitters-in-nodejs-as-opposed-to-just-calli). Thanks.